# What is the typical workflow for running "multiple" FFmpeg commands?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, workflow

For example, I have listed these out as possible commands so far:

```
# ogg to mp3
ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -acodec libmp3lame audio.mp3
# add audio to video:
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i video.mp4 video_audio_mix.mkv
# concat videos
ffmpeg -f concat -i file-list.txt -c copy output.mp4
# speed up video
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.mp4
# compress video
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1280:-1 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 24 output.mp4
# loop
# Use -1 for an infinite loop.
ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
# copy metadata
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map_metadata 0 -movflags use_metadata_tags output.mp4
# convert image to video
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.png -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
# change volume
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af 'volume=0.5' output.mp3
# increase audio tempo
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=2.0" -vn output.mp3
# add image to audio
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i input.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest output.mp4
# encode for iphone
ffmpeg -i source_video.avi input -acodec aac -ab 128kb -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1200kb -mbd 2 -flags +4mv+trell -aic 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -s 320x180 -title X final_video.mp4
# extract sound from video
ffmpeg -i source_video.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 sound.mp3
# https://catswhocode.com/ffmpeg-commands/
```

If you wanted to do this, would you run individual separate ffmpeg commands typically, or combine them into one large command?

1. rotate video 180
2. resize to 512w
3. convert to mp4
4. replace audio with another audio file

How do people typically work with ffmpeg is my basic question? Or how do apps that use ffmpeg under the hood deal with manipulating video files?

It seems more optimized to combine things into one command, but then it is a little less straightforward. Maybe apps perform 1 action at a time, and so don't combine commands? Or do you somehow specify all the operations you want to make (in some app), and then click "run", and it creates 1 optimized command (or as few commands as possible)?

Just looking to see how ffmpeg is used in production.

Comment: In most cases it's important to combine things into one command, in order to avoid re-encoding. Every time the video (or audio) is re-encoded, there is some quality degradation due to the usage of "lossy compression". There are lossless codecs, but file size is going to be extremely large (in case of video). Combine things into one command is also faster.

Comment: Typical depends on your workflow, needs, and preferences. This isn't a bad question, per se, it just isn't the sort of question we answer here on SuperUser. Your question needs opinion, advice, and an ongoing conversation. These sorts of things are better found on forums. SuperUser is about questions that can be answered with single, specific answers, and this question just isn't one of those.